# Markov Chain dependence on the present

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Given a Markov Chain $X_n$ such that $P(X_{n+1}|X_n,...X_0) = P(X_{n+1}|X_n)$. Show that

$$P(X_0|X_1,...,X_n) = P(X_0|X_1)$$

My approach was to start like
$$P(X_0|X_1,...,X_n) = \frac{P(X_0,X_1,...,X_n)}{P(X_1,...,X_n)} $$

Then I think I need to condition on something and the numerator and denominator will cancel out leaving my desired result, but so far anything I thought to condition on has not worked out.

Comment: $\mathbb P(\cdot | something)$ should take an event as an argument, not random variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prove this by induction via

\begin{eqnarray}
P(X_0\mid X_1,\ldots,X_n)
&=&
\frac{P(X_0,\ldots,X_n)}{P(X_1,\ldots,X_n)}
\\
&=&\frac{P(X_n\mid X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1})P(X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1})}{P(X_n\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})P(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})}
\\
&=&\frac{P(X_n\mid X_{n-1})P(X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1})}{P(X_n\mid X_{n-1})P(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})}
\\
&=&\frac{P(X_0,\ldots,X_{n-1})}{P(X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})}
\\
&=&
P(X_0\mid X_1,\ldots,X_{n-1})\;.
\end{eqnarray}